# Pop-up window when clicking a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, jmenuitem

I'm trying to show a pop-up window when the user clicks on a `JMenuItem`.
I've got the following piece of code:

```
menuAnular = new JMenuItem(w.translate("ETI_ANULAR"),imageAnular);
menuAnular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JDialog yesNo = new JDialog();
        yesNo.setVisible(true);
    }

});
```

Sadly, with this lines nothing is showed up. I've tried several ways to do it but I can't see nothing displayed.

Comment: can we see the custom JDialog class?

Comment: JDialog is a Class contained in the Swing library from javax. Here's the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Comment: sorry, but I can not find in the official (doc)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog()] you posted a constructor as ***JDialog(String x)***, can we see the custom JDialog class?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to erase the String from the parameters. Asume my constructor is JDialog() without params.

Comment: Probably you've forgotten to make your dialog modal? Try to add `yesNo.setModal(true);` before the line `yesNo.setVisible(true);`

Comment: your code should work...is the addActionListener getting trggered?

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can skip the guessing game

Comment: I tested your code. It works. The problem must be somewhere in the code you didn't post. Add a message to the actionPerformed-method to check if it gets invoked (or activate your debugger)

Comment: Oh, that advice about setModal() worked. Until now, I hadn't never used that inherited method... can I ask what is it used for?

Comment: Your code should work as posted.
setModal() is obsolete and should not be used. Use setModalityType. See javadoc.

Comment: *"can I ask what is it used for?"* Get it straight from the horses' mouth. 1) Visit the [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) Java Docs. 2) Find `setModal` in the page. 3) You might notice this method is inherited from `java.awt.Dialog` 4) Click the link. 5) **Read.** - Note that SO is not a substitute for reading the documentation. That documentation is vital for coding Java. Although I use an IDE that has pop-ups linked to the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), I ***always*** have them open in a tab of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuAnular.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
                popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("TITLE OF THE NEW JMENUITEM OF THE POPUP") {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                         if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(contentPanel, 
                                "Dialog", "Dialog title", 
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                         {
                           //DO SOMETHING
                         }
                    }
                }));
popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }});
```

The new POP-UP will be created in the place in which the user have clicked.

The object 'contentPanel' is the main JPanel of your application.

I hope this help.

Comment: Use an `ActionListener` for any component that accepts them. Not only will it react to mouse clicks, but also keyboard input.

Comment: You're right, I thought he just wanted the app to react to mouse clicks.

Comment: agree, JMenu / JMenuItem has own Listeners, but ActionListener is the simplest choice,